# How to identify screen and canvas coordinates for performing draganddrop using selenium and gojs

Tags: typescript, selenium, drag-and-drop, gojs

I want to perform drag and drop action on a canvas using selenium.
Where the element to be dragged is outside the canvas(i.e., element is outside the canvas panel).

Using .draganddrop() function I see that the element is dragged and is held on the mouse pointer without being dropped. The element is not dropped after providing the canvas id/ canvas coordinates.

I tried performing the drop by providing the browser screen coordinates but understood that the browser coordinates and canvas coordinates differ, so the drop action is not taking place.

Can anyone help be with a solution here.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to drag an element not in the canvas into the canvas? Is the following not working for you? `actions.drag_and_drop(source_elem, canvas_elem).perform()`?

Comment: yes this statement is right 'I want to drag an element not in the canvas into the canvas'.
actions.drag_and_drop(source_elem, canvas_elem).perform() --> this did not work.

Comment: Can you please share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?